# Is it possible to make a pivot chart a subset of pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I have a pivot table and pivot chart and they are both working fine. However, I have a couple of series in the pivot table that I don't want to show in the pivot chart. I also do not want to expand and contract the chart as I do the same in the pivot table.

**Questions**

1. Can I have a pivot chart with a subset of the series in a pivot table?
2. Can I prevent the pivot chart from changing when I expand and contract the rows in a pivot table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a pivot chart independent of your pivot table, i.e. use a separate pivot table for the chart. Then the behaviour of the Pivot Chart is not tied to the first pivot table. You can connect slicers to both pivots to ensure the same filters are applied. By default, Excel will use the same pivot cache for the second pivot table, so it does not really impact on memory or workbook performance.